# Using watson Speech to Text from a browser with websockets (Live detection)

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson

I want to use IBM Watson Speech to Text from the browser with "Live Detection" i.e. I don't want to record the audio and send files, instead I want to use the websockets option for continuous speech to text.

I found this git repo
https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-javascript-sdk

But I could not find any actual example on how to use. Can someone show me some code exaple of how to use it (or some other alternative).

I believe the `WatsonSpeech.SpeechToText.recognizeMicrophone({token})` is probably what I need and some example of hot to use it would be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's an example of it in action](https://speech-to-text-demo.mybluemix.net/)

You can find the source code for this on github [here](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-to-text-nodejs)

I think the bit you're looking for is in [/src/socket.js](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-to-text-nodejs/blob/master/src/socket.js)